# Objective C UITableView 100 000 entries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I want to create a UITableView that dynamically searches and displays matching entries. My problem is that I do not know how to store these entries. I think a plain textfile or a property list is out of question, because with those types, the whole data is loaded at the beginning.
Does anyone have an alternative to these filetypes? I read about sqlite, but is this suitable for 100 000 entries? And is it possible to performantly search for entries? (I currently have the table in a text file. The entries are seperated by a certain string.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 100'000 entries in a table... Maybe you should consider another design for your data organization...

Comment: I don't think he wants to show all 100000 at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either SQLite or Core Data (which uses SQLite) would be appropriate and should be able to handle data sets of that size with little problem.

I think you'll find that UITableView will respond acceptably even when you have that many rows in the table. You'd never want the user to actually scroll through even 1000, let alone 100,000 rows, though, so make sure you give the user a filter to really cut down the number of rows before they have to look at the data.

Important: Make sure you use a fixed row height for your table cells. If you use a variable row height, UITableView will ask you for the height of every single row in the table just so it can figure out the total height of the table. The only way you'll get decent performance is to use a fixed height.

Answer (score 1):

Core Data may be one API worth researching
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html

Core Data can be backed by several storage mechanisms, one being sqlite.  Sqlite is probably your best bet for so much data.

Comment: CoreData is the way to go.  Sounds like you'll want to be getting familiar with NSPredicate to filter fetch requests to parse your objects based on the search.